# Mac OS install application and run a script on startup

Tags: macos, package, launchd

I'm looking for a way to package my application with the added requirement that I need to add a python script to always run on startup.

What I've been trying so far is having a .pkg that installs the .app into the applications folder and adds the python script (wrapped in a .plist launch daemon) to the user's LaunchAgents folder.

I've tried a lot of different things, but for whatever reason the python script runs fine on the command line and just doesn't work when running through launchctrl. I could go into what the problems were, but I feel that would make more sense as a separate question.

I am wondering if I should be using a different approach to achieve my goal of installing the app in Applications and having a python script run on boot. Is there a more standard solution that I am missing perhaps? Thanks.

Comment: any error on console app ?

Comment: Show us your launchd plist file.